# How can I get the mic sound feedback in my headphone?

Tags: macos, audio, headphones, microphone

I bought a noise canceling headphone yesterday and it works perfectly. The only problem I have is that when I myself talk, I cannot hear my voice correctly. I'm wondered if it is possible to enable the microphone sound feedback in the audio output while the headphone is connected? I have a MacBook Pro with MacOS 10.6 installed.

Answer (score 16):

LineIn from [Rogue Amoeba](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/freebies/) lets you route any sound input to any output. Freeware.

PS: It has been updated and now works without a delay in the audio play thru!.

Comment: I have used this for all sorts of non-critical situations, however if you are going to be monitoring yourself and the lag between when you speak and when you hear your voice becomes distracting, you will want to get a hardware solution that allows less delay in the monitoring.

Comment: @bmike "hardware solution" do you have any pointers to what that might mean? thanks.

Comment: I have started using LineIn. So far, it's fine; I find that the delay is very slight and hardly noticeable. We'll see if it starts to bother me over time.

Comment: @yitz A hardware solution would be something like the Tascam iXZ which takes a XLR input from a Microphone and has a headphone jack to let you listen in before the sound gets to the iPad/Mac. There will be no delay and you can record things while you listen.

Comment: LineIn still works great, but it was replaced with a commercial tool. They still offer a free download of the original LineIn on their legacy page https://rogueamoeba.com/legacy/

Answer (score 6):

You can use GarageBand as well (see [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/58188/is-there-a-way-to-listen-to-the-input-sound-on-mac-os-x)) simply create a **new project** with **voice** and set monitor to **on**. You don't need to record to hear your voice.
[image]

Comment: Just tried to download GarageBand from the App Store, but it requires macOS version 11 or later.

Answer (score 2):

I use Audacity for recording new sounds, besides being free, it gives you the option for hardware or software Playthrough.

[image: Preferences window showing Playthrough settings]

Comment: Thanks Nilloc, but it only works while I record a sound in Audocity.

Comment: For those reading this in 2021, Audacity does allow you to monitor the mic input without recording.