# Cannot use iOS device as sound input

Tags: macos, audio

According to this article https://support.apple.com/en-ca/guide/audio-midi-setup/ams59f301fda/mac

I should be able to use my iOS device connected via usb as a sound input.

But when I follow the instruction the input is shown and I have even enabled it, the bars are even moving but no sound is heard on the mac.

[image]

Comment: If the bars are moving I would believe the input is working fine. What program are you looking to input sound into?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood this but theres no program I thought, for example if I play some music on iOS I should just hear it in the mac?

Comment: Ahh I don't believe that's how this functionality works. It should enable you to use your iPhone's microphone or audio output as an input into a program such as Facetime, Zoom or GarageBand. There might be a program which can instantly relay this to your speakers though.

Comment: This might answer your question: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11854/how-can-i-get-the-mic-sound-feedback-in-my-headphone

Comment: Doesn't look like it, linein can no longe run on macOS and audio hijack doesn't do what I want.

Comment: Your iPad is running as an input. What you need is something that will route that to an output. That's just what Audio Hijack can do. Example - https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrC3P.png

Comment: Actually, you need first something to capture the input, which can then be routed to an output. Answer added. I hadn't considered the Mac will not route in to out automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You need first something to capture the input, which can then be routed to an output.

Launch Quicktime Player, elect New Audio Recording & next to the red dot, select your input.
Turn up the volume slider underneath.
This should then route to your outputs, allowing playback. You don't even need to start the recording.
There will be latency, maybe as much as half a second.

Answer (score -1):

Open "QuickTime Player"

Now press `SHIFT + COMMAND + N` (But first press Cancel if a Finder window should open)

Now select your iPhone as input (Next to the record button) and adjust the volume of QuickTime Audio.